# Need Script to Detect object Properties - MultiValue

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I use PowerShell  mostly to work with Active Directory and MS Exchange.

Example exists to use join to report MultiValue objects, however seems cumbersome to have those lines in the script. I would like a script that would report all objects and give the standard attributes and detect multivalve properties and export them with a join character “%”.

Answer (score 0):

You mention AD and Exchange but still leave the question vague about what specifically you are querying and which are the "standard" attributes. I'm guessing you probably mean AD User attributes, but the offering below is more generalized.

You can select a list the attributes (properties) you want to retrieve from an object by putting those properties in an array and using `Select-Object`. In this example you **do** need to know in advance which properties will be multi-valued:

```
# Create an object with regular and multi-valued properties. In your
# case I guess this will come from a Get-*User cmdlet or similar.

$test = New-Object -TypeName PSOBject -Property @{"one"=1;"two"=2;"multi"=@("a","b")}

# Define the list of properties you want to return from this object.
# In this list we include a calculated column to pull the multi-valued
# data out and -join it with the '%' character

$properties = @('one','two',@{Label="multi";Expression={($_.multi) -join "%"}})

# Now we pipe our object through Select-Object to pull out those
# properties we want, including the calculated one:
$test | Select-Object $Properties

one two multi
--- --- -----
  1   2 a%b
```

Note that the name (Label) of the calculated property can be whatever you want; I used the same name as the original property.

---

Edit: The following code works for the **$test** object above, converting it into a new object where the multi-valued field is a single string with "%" joining the original array members. Note that this doesn't use prepared expressions to convert the **multi** property; instead it uses the `-ExpandProperty` switch in `Select-Object` to do the work on the fly.

```
$ConvertedProperties = @{}

foreach($Property in ($test | Get-Member -MemberType Properties)){ 
  $Value = (Select-Object -InputObject $test -ExpandProperty $Property.Name) -join "%"
  $ConvertedProperties.($Property.Name) = $Value
}

$ConvertedObject = New-Object -TypeName PSOBject -Property $ConvertedProperties

$ConvertedObject | Export-Csv filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Here is the script I went with. I just wish I could take an ad object and automatically determine the property types and output or join the multiple valued items  with a delimiter to CSV.

Comment: I guess that determining the property types could be a one-off exercise, since there is a finite list, but I understand how it would be good to find a solution that does this in the general case. Will give it some thought.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example that works for my simple test object. I hope it makes sense and gets you closer to something that works with your Active Directory.